# Spring Boot Redisson not able to read clusterServersConfig

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-webflux, redisson

Here is the application.yml I am using for my Spring WebFlux project

```yaml
redis:
  redisson:
    config: |
      clusterServersConfig:
        idleConnectionTimeout: 10000
        connectTimeout: ${REDISSON_CONNECT_TIMEOUT:20000}
        timeout: ${REDISSON_TIMEOUT:3000}
        retryAttempts: ${REDISSON_RETRY_ATTEMPTS:3}
        retryInterval: ${REDISSON_RETRY_INTERVAL:1500}
        subscriptionConnectionPoolSize: ${REDISSON_SUBSCRIPTION_POOL_SIZE:50}
        slaveConnectionMinimumIdleSize: ${REDISSON_SLAVE_MIN_IDLE_SIZE:24}
        slaveConnectionPoolSize: ${REDISSON_SLAVE_POOL_SIZE:48}
        masterConnectionMinimumIdleSize: ${REDISSON_MASTER_MIN_IDLE_SIZE:24}
        masterConnectionPoolSize: ${REDISSON_MASTER_POOL_SIZE:48}
        nodeAddresses: 
          - "rediss://${APPS_REDIS:-}:${APPS_REDIS_PORT:6379}"
        password: ${APPS_REDIS_SECRET:-}
      threads: ${REDISSON_THREADS:16}        
      nettyThreads: ${REDISSON_NETTY_THREADS:96}
```

But whenever I am starting the project in my laptop, this error comes up

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'clusterServersConfig': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
```

I am not sure why it is saying `clusterServersConfig` is an unrecognized token. In the official doc also, it is mentioned and [here](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/2.-Configuration/#242-cluster-yaml-config-format) is an example of this.

At first I thought it might be because I am running redis locally in my M1 Mac so redis-clusters aren't generated by default. I even tried to enable clusters in `redis.conf` and run a redis clusters with 3 nodes using `redis-cli` but still this happens. I have tried almost everything I could think of or search on the net. Any help appreciated :)

Comment: From the documentation you linked, nodeAddresses and the array of addresses are on the same level. Moreover the address is redis:// and not rediss://

Comment: rediss is used for SSL connection. Also the same configuration works on AWS but fails when run locally

Comment: Did you try to put only required properties and hard coding values? Just to understand if some properties could cause problems locally for some reasons.

Comment: Yes I did that but still I had the same issues with this.

Comment: If you try to configure a single node (https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/2.-Configuration/#262-single-instance-yaml-config-format), do you have issues?
Moreover, did you put configuration under "spring:"?
spring:
   redis:
     redisson:
       config: |
         clusterServersConfig:

Comment: No. For single node, it works fine. And yes, the configs are under spring.redis.redisson.config. That's why I think its because cluster nodes are not starting locally even though I use redis-cli to start the cluster with 3 nodes

Comment: How do you start cluster nodes locally? Docker compose? Which docker image do you use? Bitnami/redis-cluster, official Redis or other?

Comment: I updated the redis.conf file and then enabled clusters in it. Then via redis-cli, I did this - 
`redis-cli --cluster create localhost:6379 localhost:6379 localhost:6379`
The cluster started and I ran the application again but same thing happened. Even I made the ports different but still the same

Comment: Which version of spring boot do you use? And which version of redisson? Can you post more details of error?